# How can I determine the goals triggered during a Sitecore campaign to see the effective of the campaign?

Tags: experience-analytics, goals, campaigncreator

I have a situation where we are creating a set of campaigns to improve the conversion of goals through the use of those campaigns.  Using Experience Analytics, am I able to directly connect the triggering/tracking of campaigns to goals being triggered during the life of that campaign to make a direct assessment not just involving a timeframe ?

Answer (score 2):

If goals and campaigns are configured properly, from the moment someone lands on the site based on a campaign, all goals and engagement value gained by the user through the end of that session will be attributed to the campaign in analytics.

This is a great use of the Path Analyzer. In the Marketing Control Panel > Path Analyzer you can create a Campaign Map and assign the campaign you want to track. After you deploy that and give it time to process (24 hours or so based on config) anyone can then pull up the new Campaign Map in path analyzer and look at all goal metrics related to this.
[image: View Maps]

You could even go so far as to define what goals you want to see triggered when setting up the campaign map by defining some SCOPE that includes specific goals.
[image: Define Map]

Comment: Do the goal metrics drills down into individual goals from lets say engagement values or does it just give value and value per visit?

Comment: meant to add your name to my last comment -- @Sitecordial.  I am testing this using the Sitecore Lighthouse demo, playing with their Experience Generator in hopes I can create my own example to examine.